# What is a good technique for testing whether data is Rayleigh distributed?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, rayleigh-distribution

I have a small data set which (a) is always positive and (b) is showing a right tail on the histogram.  I wondered if it could be log-normal and tested for this, but to no avail.  I am now wondering if it is Rayleigh distributed.  Is there a standard test (either quantitative or qualitative) that I can use, preferably with MATLAB?

I am not a statistician. I am working on some theoretical engineering work and have generated some empirical data which is very surprising and positive. I now need to develop some ideas to help explain this and other observations in terms of the theory.

```matlab
data = [0.0480759077981872  0.0474242200699048  0.0498297923265934  0.0523126987560559  0.0533071484814583  0.0530870733883323  0.0529436672436650  0.0511129210314880  0.0627847479513110  0.0518733297555914  0.0482489013220388  0.0577484583274581  0.0482801585030911  0.0549646578634945  0.0509793231301709  0.0517927812000375  0.0552705448500009  0.0465748822631922  0.0502132272003582  0.0520707999895214  0.0510405616049349  0.0519205234099937  0.0469852197370555  0.0478103232904188  0.0476256698868529  0.0514493307801225  0.0486146983957451  0.0544742925738930  0.0488567824804159  0.0507673068019537]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Literally nothing you do with a sample will show you that the population distribution *is* Rayleigh (there's an infinite number of distributions that are not-Rayleigh, but nevertheless closer to your data than the Rayleigh is), but that's okay because you can bet the population distribution probably isn't *exactly* Rayleigh; even when you have a strong theoretical reason to think it should be Rayleigh, various things (like measurement error, for one example) will mean you don't quite have it in the actual data-generating process.

The best you'd normally hope for is that the Rayleigh may be a suitable/useful approximation.

George Box wrote "Remember that all models are wrong; the practical question is how wrong do they have to be to not be useful".

I think that summarizes it pretty well.

What a test could show you is that the data aren't very consistent with the population distribution being Rayleigh. However, failure to reject isn't necessarily helpful (since if your power was low you may have missed a substantial deviation from a Rayleigh), and on the other hand, rejection doesn't mean that a Rayleigh isn't a useful model (e.g. with large samples you may reject even though the Rayleigh is an excellent and useful approximation).

---

One easy way to check for whether a Rayleigh-distribution is a good approximation is to square the values and check for an exponential distribution - there are many tests and several possible diagnostic displays for that. If you must test, that's probably the easiest way to go about it -- square and test for exponential but I suggest diagnostic displays will serve you better than tests in most situations.

If you must use a goodness of fit test, it looks like the Cramer-von Mises and Anderson-Darling tests (the particular versions adjusted for the estimation of the parameter) are good omnibus tests for the exponential. See the power study in Chapter 10 of D'Agostino and Stephens' *Goodness of Fit Techniques*.

(i) Note that taking the log of an exponential would yield a shifted version of a fully specified distribution, so a Q-Q plot of the log of the square (against quantiles for the negative of a Gumbel) should yield a plot with a slope of 1 and an intercept that is related to the scale parameter of the Rayleigh.

(ii) Alternatively, the Rayleigh is a Weibull with shape parameter 2, so a Weibull plot would also work (plot log data values against $\log(-\log(1-p_i))$ for $p_i = \frac{i-\alpha}{n+1-2\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$ between $0$ and $1$. In this case, $\alpha=0.3$ is common, though $\alpha=\frac{3}{8}$ which is common in normal Q-Q plots would work just about as well (in the plots below the large-n default in R of $\alpha=\frac12$ was used). For it to be Rayleigh you'd want to see a straight line with slope $\frac12$ (given the log-data is on the y-axis). The lower tail can wobble about a lot even if the data were exactly Rayleigh, though; the same problem also occurs with the plot in (i); they only differ in slope.

Another plot that should work pretty well (and suffers less from the wiggly lower tail that you get in the Weibull plot) is to take the 1/1.8 power of the data (the 1.8th root$^\dagger$) and do a normal Q-Q plot; that should look very close to straight. I should work out an approximate intercept and slope as functions of the Rayleigh scale parameter, but I have not done so.

Here's the mentioned plots, for simulated standard Rayleigh data.

[image: Comparison of exponentiality plot of squared values, Weibull plot of values and Normal Q-Q plot of 1.8th root of Rayleigh values]

For the data in your question we can look at these plots:

[image: Comparison of exponentiality plot of squared values, Weibull plot of values and Normal Q-Q plot of 1.8th root of data values]

I didn't put on the two lines here because the curvature is strong enough that its not worth worrying about the slope of the line. The left tail is shorter and the right tail is longer than you'd expect with *any* Weibull,
so worrying about whether it might be the specific Weibull that is the Rayleigh would be a waste of time.

---

$\dagger$ I should offer some justification of that 1.8th root lest it seem I just plucked it out of thin air, or used the data to arrive at it. With Weibull distributions, a shape parameter of around $3.6$ is very close to symmetric and reasonably close to normal (the parameter we might regard transition point from left skew through sort of symmetricalish to right skew depends on how you choose to measure skewness - there's an interval of more or less plausible values that are close to symmetry and not so clearly skew one way; 3.6 is a nice roundish number in this interval). You can convert between Weibulls by taking powers. e.g. to convert an exponential (shape 1) to a Weibull with shape 3.6, you take the 3.6th root (power 1/3.6)$^\ddagger$. Similarly to convert a Rayleigh (shape 2) to a Weibull with shape 3.6 you take the 1.8th root (power 1/1.8). Simple as that!

$\ddagger$ you might then wonder -- since the exponential is also a gamma distribution, why would we not use cube roots (power $1/3$ rather than $1/3.6$), as the Wilson-Hilferty transformation would suggest. The answer to that is for gamma with large shape parameter, the Wilson-Hilferty is indeed excellent at achieving near-symmetry and approximate normality, but with small shape parameters it's too weak to attain near-symmetry, and the result is still clearly right-skew. By the time the gamma shape gets down to $1$, the power needs to be somewhere about $1/3.6$ to attain near symmetry (a fact I discovered by trial and error before realizing that it was otherwise obvious that it must be about this because of the exponential also being a special case of the Weibull and I knew this number already). At somewhat smaller gamma even stronger transformations are needed, though as we progress through a sequence of ever-smaller gamma shape parameters, power transformations soon don't work all that well at symmetrizing it.