# Smallest threshold for hypothesis test with asymptotic level alpha

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, maximum-likelihood, sampling, exponential-family

Consider a distribution with parameter $\lambda$ that has density

$$f_\lambda(x)=\frac{x^4}{24\lambda^5}e^{\frac{-x}{\lambda}},x>0$$

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be $n$ independent random variables drawn from this distribution.

I test the hypotheses $H_0:\lambda=1$ vs $H_0:\lambda≠1$ by using the test

$$\psi=\textbf{1}\big(|\bar{X}_n-5|>C_{a,n}\big)$$

I want to find the smallest threshold $C_{a,n}$ so that the test $\psi$ has asymptotic level $\alpha$. I'm choosing this test so that $C_{a,n}$ does not depend on the estimate of $\lambda$.

How do I compute $C_{a,n}$?

I already computed the MLE which also depends on the sample mean $\bar{X}_n$ but I have no idea how to apply it. I'm used to calculating a test statistic and then finding the critical value or $p$-value in order to reject or fail to reject the null at a given asymptotic level $\alpha$. Here, I don't even know the exact distribution although it looks like it belongs to the canonical exponential family. I also don't know how to calculate the value of $\bar{X}_n$ without any observations it's technically unachievable.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me out.

Comment: By inspection the distribution is in the form of a gamma (the kernel is $x$ to a power times $e^{-x/c}$). It's really useful to be able to spot the 'standard'/common exponential family distributions (gamma, normal, poisson, binomial, inverse-Gaussian, ...) as well as related distributions to those that commonly arise in models and theoretical calculations (chi-squared, beta, F, t, lognormal, logistic, uniform etc). You might find it useful to start with a table of common distributions and their properties (Casella and Berger has a good list if I recall right). Wikipedia's also a handy resource

Comment: Yes @Glen_b wikipedia is definitely bookmarked. Any suggestion on how I should tackle this one? If you need any clarification on something that I might have missed like for the other question let me know :)

Comment: This is clearly a self-study I thought a hint was in order -- my previous comment comment *was* the hint. Given the identification as a gamma, it's possible towork out the distribution of $\sum_i X_i$ and hence of $\bar{X}$ -- though you don't need it if all you're concerned with is the asymptotics -- the mean and variance and enough information to verify that a standardized $\bar{X}$ converges to a standard normal would do.

Comment: Do you know any theorems relating to distributions of standardized means?

Comment: You also don't need an exact value for the observed $\bar{x}$; what you require is a rejection rule (which you can compare the observed $\bar{x}$ or some function of it with -- you're given a function in the question, though you may initially work with some slightly different one). The subscripts on $C$ tell you that the critical value you end up with should (asymptotically) be a function only of $\alpha$ and $n$.

Comment: Hi @Glen_b thank you so much for your comments! You said that the "kernel is $$ to a power times $^{−/}$", and I'm still trying to figure out $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Although according to that info then $\alpha=5$and $\beta=\lambda$ but that $\beta$ seems off since the test does not depend on the estimate of $$. Any input on this?

Comment: I left with finding $P(|\bar{X}_n-5|>C_{a,n})=a$, where $\bar{X}_n$ is the expected value equal to $5\lambda$  and here is where I'm stuck. Can you please help me out @Glen_b ?

Comment: Again, *do you know any theorems concerning distributions of standardized sample means*?

Comment: No @Glen_b that topic is new to me. I have just dealt with test statistics up to this point. Could you perhaps share a link?

Comment: The classical central limit theorem is what you need.  See paragraph 4 (though it's a bit clumsy in use of terms):  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem  ... Basically: Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots , X_n, \ldots$, be a sequence of independent random variates from some distribution with mean $\mu$ and finite variance $\sigma^2$. Let $\bar{X}_n = (X_1+X_2 + \ldots + X_n)/n$, which is a random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2/n$. Let $Z_n = \frac{\bar{X}_n-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$. Then in the limit as $n\to\infty$, $Z_n$ converges in distribution to a standard normal.

Comment: Without it you'd have no way to get the asymptotic value of $C$. First you need to work out $\mu$ and $\sigma$, establish a suitable critical value for the limiting distribution of $|Z_n|$ (which will depend on $\alpha$ alone), then use that to back out a critical region on $|\bar{X}_n-\mu|$ which will depend on $n$ as well.

Comment: Thank you so much @Glen_b I think I'm actually starting to get it now!

Comment: Btw @Glen_b are you familiar with canonical exponential families? I'm struggling with a pdf I' trying to rewrite in canonical form posted [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/599496/writing-exponential-family-in-canonical-form) maybe you could help me out.

Comment: Alternatively, use the Lindeberg-Levy CLT lower down on that Wikipedia page. If you're trying to do problems that involve asymptotics, you need some theorems that deal with asymptotic behavior or you have nowhere to go. Many simple ones will use the law of large numbers, the central limit theorem and/or Slutsky's theorem. They each have wikipedia pages. It might also be worth checking the article relating to convergence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables . If you don't have a suitable text go here: https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/stat110/home and click "Book". Free!