# Writing exponential family in canonical form

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, exponential-family, parameterization

I have the following pdf with support $x>0$:

$$f_{\mu}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi x^3}}\textrm{exp}\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2x}\right)$$

This belongs to the exponential family, and I write this in the following form

$$f_{\mu}(x)=h(x)\space\textrm{exp}\left(\spaceη(\mu)T(x)\space-B(\mu)\right)$$

What I have thus far is by expanding the pdf is

$$h(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi x^3}}\textrm{exp}\left(-\frac{1}{2x}\right), η(\mu)=-\frac{1}{2\mu^2}, T(x)=x \space\textrm{and}\space B(\mu)=\frac{1}{\mu}$$

Something is wrong here, because when I write this in canonical form, i.e.

$$f_{\theta}(x)=h(x)\space\textrm{exp}\big(\theta x-b(\theta)\big)$$

I get the following

$$\theta=-\frac{1}{2\mu^2} \space\textrm{and}\space b(\theta)=\sqrt{-\frac{1}{2\theta}}$$

I want to rewrite the pdf in terms of $\theta$. Without this, I am unable to find the expectation, variance, fisher and so on in terms of $\theta$.

Can someone please tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Oh man @Xi'an of course $(\mu)=\frac{1}{2\mu^2}$. I will specify the support in the question right now.

Comment: I think it now makes sense for $b(\theta)=\sqrt{2\theta}$

Comment: Agreed, the minus sign is a typo and that' probably why I got it wrong all along. Thanks alot @Xi'an !

Comment: How did you pull out the minus sign @Xi'an form the square root operation? Sorry it's been a long night maybe I oversee something basic here..

Comment: Why delete the comments @Xi'an ?

Comment: He might answer it. That's why may be.

Comment: @pecer10012: I suggest you remove the comments as they hold little value for other viewers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $$f_{\mu}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi x^3}}\textrm{exp}\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2x}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi x^3}}\textrm{exp}\left(-\frac{x}{2\mu^2}+\frac{1}{\mu}-\frac{1}{2x}\right)$$
one gets that
$$\eta(\mu)=\frac{-1}{2\mu^2}\qquad B(\mu)=-\frac{1}{\mu}$$
(hence a **missing minus sign** for $B$) and for the natural parameterisation
$$\theta=\frac{-1}{2\mu^2}\qquad b(\theta)=-\sqrt{-2\theta}$$
(hence **the inverse** of the proposed $b$).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, those minus signs got the worst of me.. To follow up, this means that the canonical link function is $b(\mu )^{-1}=(-\sqrt{-2\mu})^{-1}$ @Xi'an ?

Comment: The canonical link function involves the derivative of $b(\cdot)$.